# How to specifically use on press to select a category from menu

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, react-native

const categories = [
  {
    id: "Notes Sharing",
    name: "Notes Sharing",
    image: 
  },
  {
    id: "Hostels",
    name: "Hostels",

```
image: <Entypo  name="home" size={30}/>
```

},
  {
    id: "Tutors",
    name: "Tutors",

```
image: <FontAwesome5  name="user-edit" size={30}/>
```

},
  {
    id: "Carpool",
    name: "Carpool",

```
image: <FontAwesome5  name="car" size={30}/>
```

},
..............the above is the category i want to select through the code mentioned below. and if i tap carpool option only specific page is that i want to open with it.

```
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={category.name}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Explore", { 
        category })}
        name="Carpool"
      >
```

This code helps a user to get to the explore page by tapping any button on the menu list. i want a specific button to get to that page not all of the buttons opening to the same page explore. what can i do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

try specifying your onPress then

```
_handlePress = (X) => {
 if(X === 'certain name'){
  navigation.navigate("Explore", { 
        category })
  } else {
   //do something else
  }
}

<TouchableOpacity
        key={category.name}
        onPress={this._handlePress(category.name)}
        name="Carpool"
      >
```

Comment: this didn't solve a problem. It says handlePress is not defined.

Comment: render() {
    const { color, style, ...props } = this.props;
    const dividerStyles = [styles.divider, style];

    return (
      <Block
        color={color || theme.colors.gray2}
        style={dividerStyles}
        {...props}
      />
    );
  }
}
can you please explain this code and use of{...props} here?

Comment: const categories = [
  {
    id: "Notes Sharing",
    name: "Notes Sharing",
    image: <Entypo  name="open-book" size={30}/>
  },
  {
    id: "Hostels",
    name: "Hostels",
 
    image: <Entypo  name="home" size={30}/>
  },
  {
    id: "Tutors",
    name: "Tutors",
   
    image: <FontAwesome5  name="user-edit" size={30}/>
  },
  {
    id: "Carpool",
    name: "Carpool",
  
    image: <FontAwesome5  name="car" size={30}/>
  },
  
];
this is the category section from where i have to select name in menu.